# Solving Second Order ODEs with 4 coupled equations

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'm studying rotor dynamics and I need to solve via Scipy `odeint` function the 4 ODEs for the Jeffcot Rotor with journal bearings.

The 4 equations that govern my system are:

[image]

I need to solve to find the position of the shaft uy and uz and the center position of the shaft inside the bearing ym and zm.

This is my code so far:

```py
def dSdt(S, t):
    uy, uyt, uz, uzt, ym, ymt, zm, zmt = S
    
    duy_dt = uyt
    duyt_dt = (me * omega1**2 * np.cos(omega1 * t) - c * uyt + K * (ym - uy)) / mdisco

    duz_dt = uzt
    duzt_dt = (me * omega1**2 * np.sin(omega1 * t) - mdisco * g - c * uzt + K * (zm - uz)) / mdisco
    
    dym_dt = (K * (ym - uy) - 2 * (kyy * ym + kyz * zm + dyz * zmt)) / (2*dyy)
    dzm_dt = (K * (zm - uz) - 2 * (kzy * ym + kzz * zm + dzy * ymt)) / (2*dzz)
    
    return [uyt, duyt_dt, uzt, duzt_dt, dym_dt, ymt, dzm_dt, zmt]
```

;
I'm solving via `odeint`, with all my parameters being calculated prior to calling `odeint`, but my results aren't correct.

When I plot uy by uz I should be able to see the orbit of the center of the shaft.
And the same for ym and zm.

What I'm seeing is

[image]

these are my parameters for omega1 = 5 Hz

[image]

Could you help me?

Comment: (1) Be careful which tags you choose, [tag:odeint] is not for scipy's `odeint` function. (2) You said your results aren't correct but don't explain what's wrong (don't expect us to know the correct solution to these equations). (3) Please provide enough code to run. You didn't provide values for the constants.

Comment: You should be returning 6 derivatives (2 corresponding to second derivatives, 4 to first derivatives). However, you appear to be returning 8. Why is that?

Comment: The math is expressed as a DAE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations), not a normal ODE, and the code does not correctly convert that to a system of first-order ODEs. It looks like this system can be converted to a first-order ODE system if you solve the last two equations for \dot{y_m} and \dot{z_m}. If you've done that and still have trouble, please show the math and code in first-order ODE form.